# Help in proving two metric are equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In attempting to prove that $d_1(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$ and $d_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$ induce the same (euclidean) topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, I tried first to prove that any open set in the first metric space was open in the second, that is, for every point in a ball of $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_1)$, there existed a ball of $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_2)$ contained in it. 
After a lot of tries I couldn't find such a ball so I tried instead to prove that there must be such a ball. My reasoning (by contradiction) is as follows: 
Let $B_1(p,\epsilon)$ be an arbitrary ball in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_1)$, and suppose this ball is not open in the euclidean topology. Then there must be some point $y$ pertaining to it such that its every euclidean neighbourhood is not contained in $B_1(p,\epsilon)$. Then, there must exist at least one $z \in B_2(y,\delta)$ (denoting the euclidean neighbourhoods of $y$) such that, for every $\delta>0$, $d_1(z,p)\geq \epsilon$.
But $$\epsilon \leq d_1(z,p)\leq d_1(z,y)+d_1(y,p)<2d_2(z,y)+d_1(y,p)<2\delta+\epsilon$$
Then, I reasoned that if $\delta$ can be arbitrariarly small, then $d_1(z,p)=\epsilon$. This implies that every neighborhoud lies on the boundary of the square, which is absurd given that $\delta$ can be any number. Is this ok? Can you give me some thoughts on how to improve, or even some other approach, like how to find the ball?

Comment: Didn't you ask the almost same question yesterday? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612414/proving-a-metric-induces-the-euclidean-topology

Comment: @mowzorn yes, but no one gave an answer that I could understand and as I had an entirely different approach this time I decided to ask another question

Comment: The notation $X$ is not defined.

Comment: And it seems unlikely that every ball in $(X,d_1)$ has the form $B_1(0,\epsilon)$. That would be saying that the center of every ball is $0$ (whatever $0 \in X$ is; it *looks* like a constant).

Comment: @LeeMosher it's supposed to be R two sorry it was a typo. As for the ball having center in the origin, it doesnt really matter, the argument remains the same up to translations

Comment: You should fix your typos (and other necessary fixes) by hitting the edit button.

Comment: As for your comment that "it doesn't really matter", it is nonetheless an unnecessary distraction in your proof, particularly if you fail to mention that "the argument remains the same up to translation". It's easy enough to type $p$ instead of $0$ and avoid the issue of translation.

Comment: @LeeMosher fair enough, it's just that when trying to find a ball I wanted to avoid most expressions of the type $|y_1-p_1|+|y_2-p_2|$ so when I switched to contradiction I kept using the origin. I'll edit everything now

Answer (score 2):

Let $p = (x,y)$ be any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $r>0$.

- Let $B_2 = B_2(p,r)$ be a ball in metric $d_2$. I'll show that $B_1 = B_1(p,r)\subset B_2$. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be any point in $B_1$. Then
  $$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} \leq |x-x_0|+|y-y_0|\leq r,$$
  so $(x_0,y_0)\in B_2$. We found an open ball in $d_1$ that is contained in an open ball in $d_2$.
- Let $B_1 = B_1(p,r)$ be a ball in metric $d_1$. I'll show that $B_2 = B_2\left(p,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r\right)\subset B_1.$
  For that we need to know that
  $$|a|+|b|\leq\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2}.$$
  It follows from
  $$(|a|-|b|)^2\geq 0\Leftrightarrow a^2+b^2\geq |a| |b|\Leftrightarrow 2a^2+2b^2\geq a^2+|a||b|+b^2=(|a|+|b|)^2.$$

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be any point in $B_2$. Then
$$\begin{split}|x-x_0|+|y-y_0|&\leq \sqrt{2(x-x_0)^2+2(y-y_0)^2}=\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}\leq\\
&\leq \sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r=r,\end{split}$$
so $(x_0,y_0)\in B_1$. We found an open ball in $d_2$ that is contained in an open ball in $d_1$.

How did I know to pick $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}r$ as a radius for $B_2$? Easiest way is to draw these balls, and find a radius of a circle that is inscribed in a square with a diagonal of length $2r$. In the same way we see that there is no need to change a radius when we inscribe a square in a circle.

PS: This specific reasoning works when we look at the square 'generated' by metric $d_1$. There will be diffirent radiuses, when looking at a square 'generated' by Chebyshev metric (but still easy to find by drawing them).

Comment: That's fine but is that enough to conclude they are equivalent? I thought I had to find an open ball from another topology for every point in the open ball from the other topology. And if so, why?

Comment: Two metrics are equivalent, when for any $x$ and any $r>0$ you can find $r_1,r_2$ such that $B_1(x,r_1)\subset B_2(x,r)$ and $B_2(x,r_2)\subset B_1(x,r)$. It means that if you have a ball in, let's say metric $d_1$, then you can find a ball 'inside it' in metric $d_2$, and vice versa (centered at the same point). Edit: you can find more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics

Comment: The notion of metric equivalence I am using is that two metrics are said to be equivalent if they induce the same topology. Is that notion and thd one you are using somehow the same?

Comment: Yes they are. It is there in the article I linked.

Comment: Somehow your version seemed weaker but I think I got how they are equivalent.

Comment: I'd still appreciate some feedback on my attempt at proving it by contradiction, would you consider giving some remarks?